# Consuming JSON-data in iOS

Tags: ios, json, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch, nsjsonserialization

I am confused about JSON consuming in iOS. I am trying to use `NSJSONSerialization`.

I found a tutorial from [Ray Wenderlich discussing working with JSON on iOS5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) using dispatch async.

But in some tutorials I found, they were using `NSURLConnection`.

Don't kick me for I am really a newbie here.

Comment: I tried to fix your question - still you seem to mixup some things. `NSJSONSerialization` is for en/decoding JSON data. `NSURLConnection` is for retrieving remote (e.g. JSON) data. `GCD` is commonly used for multithreading. All three components are entirely different in nature but well suited for being combined.

Comment: halo @Till any documentation how to combine it? or article/tutorials for it? because if it separate sample.. will make confuse

Comment: You need to tell us what you want to do specifically, and show us what you've tried so far. Saying you want to "combine" them isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Best one I have seen so far:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jh0bHASUnvY